# How to get friends list using four square api in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to include facebook api into my iphone application .And also i want to list of friends using foursquare api ....

Is it possible ?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 4):

You can download source code for the four square api from the github using this link

https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2

after that use iOS API for iPhone

to find friend list for the user use the following method

```
if ([Foursquare2 isNeedToAuthorize]) {
    [self authorizeWithViewController:self Callback:^(BOOL success,id result){
        if (success) {
            [Foursquare2  getDetailForUser:@"self"
                                  callback:^(BOOL success, id result){
                                      if (success) {
                                          // NSLog(@"%@",result);
                                      }
                                  }];
        }
    }];
}else {


    [Foursquare2 getFriendsOfUser:@"self" callback:^(BOOL success, id result){
                                            if (success) {
                                            NSLog(@"%@",result);
                                            }
                                        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the facebook SDK for iOS [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

and get information on the Foursquare API [here](http://developer.foursquare.com/)